# Usage of spend with preposition 'on' or without preposition 'on' in clauses

Tags: grammar, ing

Sometimes we use *spend* like "spend something on doing something" but sometimes we are using without **on** like "I spend a lot of time working on  this project". Is there any difference between these usages? If yes, what is the difference? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326756/spend-on-or-spend

Comment: I had controled early questıons before I asked;however, I missed this questıon. If I saw it, I  wouldn't ask. Thanks for link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In those situations, on is *optional*.

But use *on* no more than once:

- Right: *I spent a lot of time working on this project.*
- Right: *I spent a lot of time on this project.*
- Wrong: *I spent a lot of time on working on this project.*

*Sth* is not a word.

Comment: I spent time working.... (here working is an adv.).  'I spent time on working' makes 'working' a verbal noun.

Comment: .
.. so Right: I spent a lot of time on reading.